# Deploying a precompiled f# function to Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a f# project that contains two functions. I can run theses locally and when I do `func start` (or start debug with `F5` it in VS Code). One of the two functions copy data from one azure storage container to another and the other function copies some data from a DB and puts it in an azure storage container. All this works nicely when I run it locally. Now I would like to deploy these to Azure Functions. I have created a resource group, created the Function app and ensured that the Function App settings indicate that it is a Azure function version 2. When I try to deploy the functions via:

```
func azure functionapp publish <FUNCTION APP NAME>
```

The code is uploaded to Azure. And the output is:

```
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading archive...
Upload completed successfully.
Syncing triggers...
```

In Azure portal under deployment options I see that a deployment has been triggered and looking at the details for the latest one I get:

> Mon 09/17 Updating submodules.
>   Mon 09/17 Preparing deployment for commit id '75833a2816'.
>   Mon 09/17 Generating deployment script. View Log
>   Mon 09/17 Running deployment command... View Log
>   Mon 09/17 Running post deployment command(s)...
>   Mon 09/17 Syncing 2 function triggers with payload size 317 bytes successful.
>   Mon 09/17 Deployment successful.

This seems to indicate that two functions have been found and successfully deployed. However, the functions are not listed under the Functions under the Function App. And I have not been able to make successfull calls to them.

**Do I have to provide some additional configuration in order to run a F# application as an Azure Function v2?**

Comment: If you can share the name of a test function app in that state, we can look at logs from our end

Comment: Excellent! The function app is named: `BokioMLDataExtractorFunctionsTest`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see in the logs for Function App `BokioMLDataExtractorFunctionsTest`:

```
CopyImagesToBokioAIStorage: Invalid script file name configuration. The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does not exist.
CopyOcrToBokioAIStorage: Invalid script file name configuration. The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does not exist.
```

That is why the two functions are not showing up. Hopefully that helps figure out the issue?

Comment: This was indeed the problem, I had published the function from the command line from the root of the project (which contained subfolders with `function.json` files). Publishing from the folder where the compiled code resided resolved the issue.   

Is there a way to get hold of the logs where these errors show up? I found them hidden away in a subfolder when I downloaded a diagnostics dump via Kudu, but there ought to be an easier way to access those logs...

Comment: I'm surprised that they did not show up in the portal at some level. I would say this is an error reporting bug.